# How to set fake GPS location on IOS real device using GPX file without code access?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, location, gpx

I need to test the scenario where looking for near by places of US location while I am in India. I have GPX file having coordinates of US location but I do not have code access so how can I use this GPX file to make fake location?

Answer (score 1):

In **iOS Simulator Menu**, go to **Debug -> Location -> Custom Location**. There you can set the latitude and longitude and test the app accordingly. This works with **MapKit** and also with **CLLocationManager**.

Comment: Thanks but I know about it I need to test it on device only.